# Higher variance in PCA can mean, that data structure is less informative?

Tags: data, pca

I have the possibility to describe data with two different data structures, both data structures are some sort of approximation to the true data. I would like to compare the two data structures with respect, how much one explains variance in one data structure to the other.

Therefore I decided to use PCA, nevertheless, I don't know if it safe to say such statement: If the variance explained by the same number components N (e.g. 2) is higher in a data structure than in the other, the data structure loses some part of the information. For example as on the image below, if Data_structure_A gives more variance, then it loses more information than Data_structure_B?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not the best use of Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to compare information loss for different data structures.

It would be more appropriate to use [Information Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory). Information Theory is the study of data compression. It provides many tools to make quantitative comparisons across different encoding schemes.

Comment: That's a good point. But could you narrow down your answer, e.g. some group of methods? It would be very helpful!

Comment: I can not suggest specific methods because I'm unclear about the specific data and specific data structure.

Comment: Brian Spiering - the data structure is a set of graphs, that have feature vector associated with a node or weighted edges. It is explained in detail here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/75284/how-to-tell-how-much-information-i-lose-when-i-simplify-the-graph-data-structure